# REST API Workflow Task not change its state

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

We are shifting our code from .Net - C# to REST API for Workflow TASK Approval process.

We have successfully change the update item in Workflow Task list, but Workflow not change its status using REST API Code.

```
$( document).ready(function() {


    $.ajax({
          url: "https://myonlinesite.sharepoint.com/it/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Workflow%20Tasks')/items/getById('4609')",
             type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Workflow_x0020_Tasks1ListItem' }, 'Status':'Completed', 'PercentComplete':'100','Nintex_x0020_Task_x0020_Outcomes':'Approved' }),
             headers: { 
                 "X-HTTP-Method":"PATCH",
                 "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                 "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                 //"content-length": 1000,
                 "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                 "IF-MATCH": "*"
             },
              beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {                     
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
                },  
             success: function (data) {
                 // Returning the results
                 console.log('success');
             },
             error: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
             }
    });
    });
```

[image]

Above script mark item as completed, but unable to reach at second approve level (not changing its state).

Comment: "We are shifting our code from .Net - C# to REST API for Workflow TASK Approval process" why?

Answer (score 0):

through rest you can update the column of workflow but you cannot you update extended property "Task.ModerationInformation.Status" which result to fire the workflow. The above property is only accessible in server object model.

For example

```
 task.ModerationInformation.Status = SPModerationStatusType.Approved;
```

Comment: The OOTB workfow is already running and the Workflow Manager is checking this ModerationInformation. You could write your own  workflow which checks status on every Item Update... maybe.. maybe all it takes is just to touch the  Item .. because then the Workflow Manager is involved (and I presume the Manager notifies any other pending Workflows) (Which your REST update does not) (note: ideally we want to communicate with the WorkflowManager (workflow instance) ourselves.. last time I checked (2015) nothing much was available with REST/JSOM) And with Microsofts focus on Flow I don't expect much